# How to set resources directory in eclipse dynamic web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, location, classpath

I want to build a web project which uses minimum libraries. So what I did is just described below

- Make a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse(Luna)
- Configure as Maven Project
- And import some libraries in pom.xml
- Implement `WebApplicationInitializer`

I made 2 configuration classes and initializer it looks like...

`RootConfig.java` which intend to replace 'root-context.xml'...

```
@Configuration
public class RootConfig {

    @Value(value="${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String jdbcDriverClassName;

    @Value(value="${jdbc.url}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Value(value="${jdbc.username}")
    private String jdbcUsername;

    @Value(value="${jdbc.password}")
    private String jdbcPassword;

    private static final String RESOURCE_LOCATION = "resources";

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholder() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]{ 
                new ClassPathResource(RESOURCE_LOCATION + File.separator + "properties"
                        + File.separator + "jdbc" + File.separator + "jdbc.properties")
        };
        ppc.setLocations(resources);
        return ppc;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(this.jdbcDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(this.jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(this.jdbcUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(this.jdbcPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }
};
```

and this is `ServletConfig.java` which suppose to be replacement of 'servlet-context.xml'...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages= {
            "com.gosports.api.controller"
            , "com.gosports.common.controller"
            , "com.gosports.test.controller"
    }
    , excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class)
)
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver () {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        vResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        vResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return vResolver;
    }
}
```

Finally, My initializer...

```
public class WASInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext arg0) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(RootConfig.class);
        context.register(ServletConfig.class);

        context.setServletContext(arg0);
        Dynamic servlet = arg0.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
};
```

and it works since I put my 'jdbc.properties' file in `/{project_location}/src/resources/properties/`.

But what I want to do is put this file in `/WEB-INF/resources/properties/`.
I can not absolute path in code, considering distribution.

I need to refer relational location from project server. There are some ways to find that directory with `HttpServletRequest` and `ServletContext`, but I can not do like that because those part- `propertyPlaceholder()` part - is static method.

Is there any good example or solution to do that?
I really do not want to use Spring Templates or xml.
Is it possible what I am trying to do with only java files?

Thanks for you answer :D

Comment: Just put it where it was and prefix with `classpath:`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. If you do not mind, I would like ask one more question. How to print `classpath:` in static method? I also often used that keyword in config.xml. But in Java class... I do not know.

Comment: It is just a string, nothing more nothing less. You are thinking to complex... Also see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shouldn't be using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` anymore but a `PropertySOurcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead. Next instead of loading your files yourself, just use `@PropertySource` on your class. Put your files in `src/main/resources` and then maven will add it to the class path.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/properties/jdbc/jdbc.properties")
public class RootConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySources PlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholder() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

This assumes that all your properties are in `src/main/resources` in the directory structure as you created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D. But if you do not mind I want to ask a extra question. You said I should not use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` anymore. I want to know reason. I visited documentation page, but what I found is one of its method is deprecated, not whole class. Thanks again.

Comment: I think this answer should work properly. So I took as an answer. However, what I wanted was little bit different, so I also add a comment below this. I hope my answer would be a hand to junior devs like me. b

Comment: The `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is a lot more powerful then the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. The latter only operates on properties loaded through property files or system properties. However the property sources is a lot more flexible it can use the system environment, system properties, servletcontext, jndi, property files or whatever you seem fit to use as a `PropertySource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the classLoader as returned by Thread#getContextClassLoader().

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

The /WEB-INF folder is not in the root of the classpath but its /WEB-INF/classes folder from where you need to load the properties files relative to.

```
classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/jdbc.properties");
```

Or you could read them as resource which shall always work.

```
AppServiceClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/jdbc.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your answers :D

but maybe my explanation was not enough, so I have to find my way out. Following is my solution to set resources folder for Dynamic Web Project.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);;
}
```

Frankly, I under stood till `addResourceLocations`, but did not about `setCachePeriod`. This was a solution I was looking for.